# Partial derivative of summation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am not sure how to solve this partial derivative in respect to $\theta$. The portion that is confusing me is the summation portion. I assume that because the summation does not have $\theta$ we can just "pull it out" and it is not in respect to $\theta$.

Here we have $\langle\theta,x^i\rangle$ representing the dot product. I have that portion figured out.

$$\dfrac{\partial\sum_{i=0}^n log(1 + exp(y^i\langle\theta,x^i\rangle))}{\partial\theta}$$

From my understanding

$$\dfrac{\partial\sum_{i=0}^n log(1 + exp(y^i\langle\theta,x^i\rangle))}{\partial\theta}$$

would be treated the same as

$$\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^n \partial log(1 + exp(y^i\langle\theta,x^i\rangle))}{\partial\theta}$$

where I can start solving and ignoring the summation ($\sum_{i=0}^n$) portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's differentiate with respect to $\theta_j$.

\begin{align}\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^n \partial \log(1 + \exp(y^i\langle\theta,x^i\rangle))}{\partial\theta_j} &= \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{y^ix^i_j}{1+\exp(y^i\langle \theta, x^i\rangle)}\\
\end{align}

We have found the $j$-th component of the derivative.

Comment: How come $\theta_j$ ? Is it because on top $\theta$ is the vector itself and $\theta_j$ is the jth element of the vector $\theta$ ?

Comment: I got to your solution but I also have $1/ln(10)$. Any reason you decided to ignore that? or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, $\theta$ is a vector. I interpreted $\log$ in your original post as $\log_e$. You should get a constant mulitple if you interpreted it as other base.